# Find duplicate rows and sum the values of two column

Tags: excel, vba

Sample data

```
A(Name)     B(Mat_Num)  C(Items) D(group)   E(Summon)   F(Plant) G(Batch_num)
1.Ram       1235         HA1      Micro      545.5      1327      893A1
2.ram       12354        rt2      Senf       5678       0001      1063F
3.Joseph    12354        cf1      Macro      9844       0001      1063F
4.andreas   12354        dw1      HR         6633.95    0001      1063F
5.John      1235         ff1      Finance    22555.09   1327      893A1
6.Russel     987         ad1      Sales      6423       0001      jjg67
7.Holger      00         dd1      purchase   3333       1327      dd567
8.Gottfried   234        fa1      rot        663        345       45678
```

I have to find duplicate rows based on columns (c, F, G). If the rows of these three columns are the same then sum the value of cells of column E and Column B to one row and delete duplicate rows to keep only one of the rows.

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this.

Comment: I just want to do by vba ... Anyone can help me out pls ...

Comment: What *specifically* is giving you problems with this ? If you don't know *any* VBA this is not really the place for tutorials.

Comment: Well I have the code but I am not able to sum of 2 column as I can only sum on column ... That's the reaso I am asking

Comment: If you have code, then posting it will greatly improve your chances of getting useful responses.

Comment: @TimWilliams   below are the code  Sub Sum_and_Dedupe()
    With Worksheets("sheet1")
        'deal with the block of data radiating out from A1
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            'step off the header and make one column wider
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count + 1).Offset(1, 0)
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).Formula = "=sumifs(g:g, d:d, d2, e:e, e2, f:f, f2)"
                .Columns(7) = .Columns(.Columns.Count).Value
                .Columns(.Columns.Count).Delete
            End With

Comment: 'remove duplicates
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(4, 5, 6), Header:=xlYes
        End With
        .UsedRange
    End With
End Sub

Comment: Please edit your question to add the code there - no-one can really read code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

@Manoj

Use a pivot table ontop on your raw data.

This will aggregate values and remove duplicate's for you with very minimal effort.

In order to remove the manual work, you will need to set up a named range and use that as your Range when creating the pivot table.

Bellow is your sample and i added a few duplicates in. "Customer_Number" is in A1.

[image]

You can then set up a named range using the following formula within the Named Range group on the Formulas Tab.

`=OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$A:$A),8)`

This will count the number of rows you have so when new data is apended to the bottom of your Raw Data table, you only need to refresh the pivot and all your new data will pull through.

The Number 8 is the total columns in your data set.

You can then use the pivot table with a classic view and no sub-totals to display the aggregated data as bellow

[image]

Once your pivot table is set up and the named range is in place, hitting the Refresh button within the Pivot Table will update will pull through your updated Raw Data with the New data appended in.